# ICollectionView Sort doesn't work after changing source

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sorting, icollectionview

I have a method that queries a database using entity framework and places the results in an `ICollectionView`. The `ICollectionView` acts as the `ItemsSource` for a `DataGrid`. Everything works fine on the first query, but upon querying a second time, the data is not properly sorted, despite the application of the correct `SortDescriptions`.

Here is my code for trying querying and grouping/sorting the data:

```
    CollectionViewSource cvsRS;

    private ObservableCollection<productorder> rs;
    public ObservableCollection<productorder> RS
    {
        get { return rs; }
        set
        {
            if (rs != value)
            {
                rs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RS");
            }
        }
    }

    private ICollectionView rsView;
    public ICollectionView RSView
    {
        get { return rsView; }
        set
        {
            if (rsView != value)
            {
                rsView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RSView");
            }
        }
    }

    public void QueryDatabase()
    {

        RS = new ObservableCollection<productorder>(DatabaseEntities.productorders.Where(o => o.month.id == CurrentMonth.id));
        if (RS != null)
        {
            cvsRS.Source = RS;
            RSView = cvsRS.View;

            RSView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            RSView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("producttype.productcategory.name"));
            RSView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("producttype.name"));  

            RSView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            RSView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("producttype.productcategory.sortorder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            RSView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("client.name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            RSView.Refresh();
            CurrentRecord = null;
            SelectedRecords = null;
        }
    }
```

The grouping works fine, but the groups aren't in the correct order based on the sorting. I've tried a number of possible "fixes" with no success (e.g. adding sort/group descriptions directly to the `CollectionViewSource`, sorting before grouping, removing some of the sorting/grouping, removing the `SortDescriptions` per [CollectionViewSource does not re-sort on property change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271048/collectionviewsource-does-not-re-sort-on-property-change)).

Does anyone know how to maintain the sort order regardless of how many queries are performed? I'm open to alternative methods of querying displaying the data in the `DataGrid` if that may work.

Comment: I'd try binding the Source (not assign, bind, using an instance of the `Binding` class) once, to an `ObservableCollection<T>` property which raises `PropertyChanged` when you give it a new collection. Then repopulate by changing the property. Either toss in a new collection, or clear and repopulate the old one. But don't ever touch `cvsRS.Source` except to set up the `Binding` initially.

Comment: Hopefully I interpreted this correctly, I did this in my constructor:             `cvsRS = new CollectionViewSource();
 cvsRS.Source = new Binding("RS");
 RSView = cvsRS.View;`
But I get an error: 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' is not a valid value for property 'Source'.

Comment: I whipped up a quick test and it worked as I expected, so I posted an answer with an example of how to do the binding. Pasting that into a comment would be unreadable anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding your `CollectionViewSource.Source` property to your `ObservableCollection<T>` property. Set up the binding in the viewmodel constructor. Then, just leave it alone. Update the `ObservableCollection<T>`, replace it, etc. As long as it's an `ObservableCollection<T>` and its public property raises `PropertyChanged` whenever you replace it, the whole thing will work.

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    BindCollectionViewSource();
}

protected void BindCollectionViewSource()
{
    cvsRS = new CollectionViewSource();

    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = this,
        Path = new PropertyPath("RS")
    };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(cvsRS, CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, binding);
}

//  Since we're not going to be messing with cvsRS or cvsRS.View after the 
//  constructor finishes, RSView can just be a plain getter. The value it returns 
//  will never change. 
public ICollectionView RSView
{
    get { return cvsRS.View; }
}
```

You can't just assign a binding to `Source`; there's more to it than that. The `Source="{Binding RSView}"` stuff you see in XAML may look like an assignment, but some details are being hidden for convenience. The `Binding` actively does stuff. It needs to know who the target object is.

I did see one funny thing: I gave my test code one `PropertyGroupDescription` and one `SortDescription`. When I added items to the collection, it sorted them within the groups. Then when I called RSView.Refresh(), it resorted them without reference to the groups. Not sure I understood what it was doing there.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I've implemented the code above, but my `DataGrid` never shows any data now. Its `ItemsSource` is bound to `RSView`. I also kept my `QueryDatabase` method identical, with the exception of removing `cvsRS.Source = RS; RSView = cvsRS.View;`

Comment: Just for now try RS.Clear() and Add items to it, instead of creating a new collection.

Comment: @matthew_b Ohhhh -- another thing I forgot, may need RSView.Refresh() when stuff changes.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary (just tested it), though I already had that implemented. Thanks again.