# Implenting ListCollectionView From ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, filtering, observablecollection

I recently posted a question onto CodeReview ([CodeReview Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128855/slow-filtering-method-on-datagrid)) and following their advice I am looking from moving from an `ObservableCollection` to an `ICollectionView` to a `ListCollectionView` instead as apparently a `ListCollectionView` has better filtering performance.

What I do at the moment is this;

```
Contracts = await ReturnContracts();
ContractsICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contracts);
DataContext = this;
```

Where `Contracts` is the `ObservableCollection` and `ContractsICollectionView` is the `ICollectionView`. When I use a `ListCollectionView` instead I get this error;

*Cannot convert from ICollectionView to ListCollectionView.*

Here is the definition of `Contracts` and `ContractsListCollectionView`;

```
public ObservableCollection<ContractModel> Contracts;
public ListCollectionView ContractsListCollectionView { get; private set; }
```

My question is how can I implement `ListCollectionView` and take advantage of its improved filtering?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare `ContractsListCollectionView` like this:

```
public ICollectionView ContractsListCollectionView { get; private set; }
```

Alternatively, if you really need use `ListCollectionView` methods, and not just `ICollectionView` (note that `ListCollectionView` implements `ICollectionView`), then you need to make a cast:

```
ContractsICollectionView = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contracts);
```

Note that while for `ObservableCollection` `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` indeed returns `ListCollectionView` - for other collection types it might not be the same and cast will fail. However since you are using it only with `ObservableCollection` - cast is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am attempting to use `ListCollectionView` because of its apparent increased performance with large DataSets (I have about 28000 Companies to filter).

Comment: In both methods above the _underlying_ type will be ListCollectionView. It's just in first case you access it via interface (ICollectionView) and in second case directly. So if you don't use it directly and for example just bind your grid to it - use first appoach.